# Cannot inherit Asp.Net Core App 2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-core

I have a web site created with netcoreapp2.1. This web site is a base for other web sites (BaseWeb). In earlier versions i could create a new web site (AddOnWeb) that inherited from the base web site (By adding a Project reference), and then i could create new views and styling, or override different stuff, or register custom services.

Now with version 2.1 that does not seem to work any more. there are 2 issues:

1. If i try to use views in AddOnWeb i get this error:

One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]

The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

+
[assembly:global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.RazorViewAttribute(@"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index))]

Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported

+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]

Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported

+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]

...and it continues

2. If i register another Startup class in
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup();
   all paths returns error 404

I have uploaded a solution that illustrates the problem here https://filebin.net/eo3an22cisfg6kpn/BaseWeb.zip?t=0gt49qkp. Any help would be greatly appreciated

An additional thing i am wondering about is why the AddOnWeb project must include the AspNetCore.App nuget package, i thought it would get it through the BaseWeb project it references

br
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Seems this could be fixed by making my own IRouter. It was a part of a larger project also with it's own ViewEngine, so that might also be a part of the solution. If time permits in the future i might investigate this further